# How to toggle event listener on javascript matchmedia

Tags: javascript, media-queries, addeventlistener

I need to know how can i toggle an event listener that works when the screen is less than 700px and when the screen is more than 700px the event listener gets removed

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.getElementById("resources").addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("media worked")
    })
  } else {
    document.getElementById("resources").removeEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("media worked")
    })
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 979px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">abrir y cerrar</h1>
  <button id="resources">click to toggle</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use named functions if you want to use `removeEventListener`, since the function that you remove has to be the same one you added.

```js
function clickHandler() {
  alert("media worked");
}

function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.getElementById("resources").addEventListener("click", clickHandler)
  } else {
    document.getElementById("resources").removeEventListener("click", clickHandler)
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 979px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">abrir y cerrar</h1>
  <button id="resources">click to toggle</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Barmar** has given the correct answer to the problem of your code. But I still wanted to add this to show that it's a possibility.

You could use CSS to, for example, disable a click on an element uing the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

function onClick(event) {
  console.log(event);
  event.preventDefault();
}

links.forEach(function(link) {
   link.addEventListener('click', onClick);
});
```

```css
.events-none {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Without pointer-events: none</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="events-none">With pointer-events: none</a>
```